# wait to download jquery.js before completing the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if the user is authenticated before accessing private pages of my app. 
The plan is to write a script at the top of every page that downloads the jquery, connect to the server and check the connection and redirect the user to login page if he/she is not logged in.

For example, this is the private.html page

```
    <script src="/js/jquery"> //put a function that will till the download is completed before  running  the liness below
    <script>
        $.ajax(ur:"/server/checkif user is logged");

     </script>   

     //other html elements
```

Comment: This kind of authentication check would better be handled by the server rather than the client, don't you think?

Comment: It's a server-side job. Not client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it. It is **unsecure and unreliable**. As others have mentioned, the client has already received the entire page *before* JavaScript has even started to execute.

This kind of authentication should be done on the server side. Since you didn't tag a server-side programming language explicitly, I can only offer a generic route to achieve this:

- First check if the client is 'logged in'
- If not, do not create the original page intented to be shown to such clients
- Instead show a login form

It is important that - in this context - private data is not even sent to the client, only if it's authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop page loading by JavaScript, because resource loading and execution of its contents are two separate things. (Anyone can download the whole page to a file and the script inside won't get executed.) You need to perform authentication and redirection on your server.

Even if you checked authentication using JavaScript and only then loaded the content programatically, you'd be running into the exact same problem (users could hijack your script and just download your content directly).